# Finding Smallest Substring Containing All Characters In A Vector Page 1 of 1

Tags: c++, string, search, vector, substring

I came across this problem on a list of software dev interview example problems and have been trying to solve it. I came up with a version that works in most cases, but one of my test cases is failing and I can't figure out whats going wrong.

Failing test:

> Input: ["A","B","C"], "ADOBECODEBANCDDD"
>
> Expected result: "BANC"
>
> Program output: "ADOBEC"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getShortestUniqueSubstring( const vector<char>& arr, const string &str )
{
  int minsize = str.size() + 1;
  string minstr = "";

  if (str.size() >= arr.size())
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
      {
          for (int j = i + 1; j <= str.size(); j++)
          {
                if (j - i >= arr.size())
                {
                    string sub = str.substr(i, j);
                    bool found = true;

                    for (int k = 0; k < arr.size(); k++)
                    {
                        if (sub.find(arr[k]) == string::npos)
                            found = false;
                    }

                    if (found == true && sub.size() < minsize)
                    {
                        if (minsize == arr.size())
                            return sub;

                        minsize = sub.size();
                        minstr = sub;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
  return minstr;
}

int main()
{
  string inputstr = "ADOBECODEBANCDDD";
  vector<char> arr = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

  cout << getShortestUniqueSubstring(arr, inputstr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through it with a debugger?

Comment: `string::substr()` takes an index and a length, not two indices.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) { for (int j = i + 1; j <= str.size(); j++)` -- `O(n^2)` solutions are usually frowned upon by "software dev" interviewers.

Comment: Uhg n^2, yea that is bad. Guess I need to do some searching and figure out how else it can be done... Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, ensure that you properly call `str.substr()`; you need to pass in the starting index of the substring and its **length**, not its ending index.

So instead of:

```
string sub = str.substr(i, j);
```

Make sure you pass in the length:

```
string sub = str.substr(i, j - i);
```